# Missing Assembly Reference?

Tags: ios, .net, sqlite, xamarin

```
namespace imPACt.Interfaces  //don't know if this is necessary, was done in tutorial
{
    public interface ISQLiteInterface
    {
        SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection();
        SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection();
        SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection();
    }
}
```

So basically I keep getting the following errors when I try to run the iOS portion of the app. I know it probably has something to do with a missing package, but I'm not sure which one?  Any ideas?

Errors are as follows:

[error_description_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6vrQ.png)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use [this](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), which means you need to install [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl). I have no experience with this package, I just searched Google for ["sqlite.net"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sqlite.net%22) and that was the first result.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: Hi , if is a Xamarin.iOS project , you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/data/using-sqlite-orm) to check where problem is.

Comment: Remove screenshot and paste error by editing your question